# Get General Type of class<T> use Type of Type

Tags: c#

I have a General Class named MyGeneralClass:

```
public MyGeneralClass<T> {

public List<T> Data {get; set;}

}
```

also I have another method that I need to use it:

```
public void GetData(Type type) {



}
```

I Use `GetData`like this:

```
GetData(typeof(MyGeneralClass<person>));
```

So my question is that how can I find type of `T`, (in this example `person`) in `GetData` method, I can't change the parameters of `GetData` but I can change implementation of that. Does any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via reflection:

```
if(type.IsGenericType &&
     type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyGeneralClass<>))
{
   Type firstArg = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

Comment: `var myClass = new MyClass<int>();           
    GetType(typeof(MyClass)); // type.IsGenericType is false      
    GetType(myClass.GetType()); // type.IsGenericType is true`  How to go around that?

Comment: @MichalB `MyClass` is completely unrelated to `MyClass<int>` - `MyClass` is a non-generic type; `MyClass<>` is an *open* generic type; `MyClass<int>` is a *closed* generic type

Comment: @Marc Gravell: oops. I forgot to add <int> when I was checking it :P. Works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method:

```
Type t = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

[Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) returns an array of the generic arguments, i.e., `{person}` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) for that purpose.

```
Type[] genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
```

And in your case, Person will be the first type in this array.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof(MyGeneralClass<person>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```